# Invoke method on event handler in Delphi

Tags: delphi

As following an example of a code written in C# that use an SDK (in-proc COM object)
I've created a class: TSwitcherMonitor, and now I've to assign the callback function to my object property: OnSwitcherDisconnected property. I've this call example in C#, the note talk about double use of lambda expressions. I've googled on this and it seem that Delphi does not have lambda expression.

Here is the call in C#:
Q1: There is a way to do the same way in Delphi using the invoke method or we have to do this in a different way ?

```
//Create callbacks object
  m_switcherMonitor := TSwitcherMonitor.Create(Application.Handle);
  // note: this invoke pattern ensures our callback is called in the main thread. We are making double
  // use of lambda expressions here to achieve this.
  // Essentially, the events will arrive at the callback class (implemented by our monitor classes)
  // on a separate thread. We must marshell these to the main thread, and we're doing this by calling
  // invoke on the Windows Forms object. The lambda expression is just a simplification./
  m_switcherMonitor.OnSwitcherDisconnected += new SwitcherEventHandler((s, a) => this.Invoke((Action)(() => SwitcherDisconnected())));
```

Q2 : The only thinks I want, is to have a working callback on using the SDK. Does my declaration of TSwitcherEventHandler is correct ?

In reference, here is my TSwitcherEventHandler  declaration and my TSwitcherMonitor class:

```
Type
{TSwitcherEventHandler}
  TSwitcherEventHandler = procedure(const sender: TObject; const args: TObject) of object;

{TSwitcherMonitor}
  TSwitcherMonitor = Class(TComObject, IBMDSwitcherCallback)
  private
    FHwnd: HWND;
    FSwitcherDisconnected: TSwitcherEventHandler;
  published
    constructor Create(hWnd: HWND);
  public
    function Notify(eventType: _BMDSwitcherEventType): HResult; stdcall;
    property OnSwitcherDisconnected: TSwitcherEventHandler read FSwitcherDisconnected write FSwitcherDisconnected;
  end;

implementation
{ TSwitcherMonitor }
constructor TSwitcherMonitor.Create(hWnd: HWND);
begin
  FHwnd:= hWnd;
end;

function TSwitcherMonitor.Notify(eventType: _BMDSwitcherEventType): HRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  if eventType = bmdSwitcherEventTypeDisconnected then
    if assigned(FSwitcherDisconnected) then
      FSwitcherDisconnected(self, nil);

  result := S_OK;
end;
```

Comment: Hard to see where C# comes into this. Isn't it a pure Delphi question? Delphi has anonymous procedures which are equivalent to C# lambdas.

Comment: @Heffernan, Merry Christmas! , the C# come as the exemple I have is in C# and I don't understand the " invoke((action) " part of the event handle assignement.

Comment: Also, on this line of code, when in C# it assign the event handler to the OnSwitcherDisconnected, it use "=+ new" of a SwitcherEventHandle, which is my TSwitcherEventHandle but this is not an object and I can not create an instance of it. This what I do not understand and I can not figure how to write this call in Delphi.

Comment: Invoke runs the code on main thread. In Delphi it is TThread.Synchronize.

Comment: This is not finished (more work in progress) but if I understand well the call will look like this:  m_switcherMonitor.OnSwitcherDisconnected := TThread.Synchronize(TSwitcherEventHandler);

Comment: No. That won't work. You need to invoke Synchronise from your event handler. Or invoke it from Notify. It all depends. Hard to tell from here. How much Delphi do you know? You don't seem familiar with procedural types.

Comment: Near beginner, I know I miss something important in the concept, in the same way as my Q2 was, does my event handler declaration is correct ?  TSwitcherEventHandler = procedure(const sender: TObject; const args: TObject) of object;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43890/discussion-between-alain-v-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: where is `inherited Create()` in `TSwitcherMonitor` contrustror?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a "Delphi experts" but for shure, as many says, Delphi Rocks !

The C# line:

```
m_switcherMonitor.OnSwitcherDisconnected += new SwitcherEventHandler((s, a) => this.Invoke((Action)(() => SwitcherDisconnected())));
```

can be translated in Delphi as simple as:

```
m_switcherMonitor.OnSwitcherDisconnected := switcherMonitor_OnSwitcherDisconnected;
```

Now my sample application work. Delphi do some automatic job with pointer and when tranlating C# or C++ code in Delphi just writing it in is more simple expression and Delphi do the job. At the start, it's weird and hard to work with this kind of black magic, when we try to understand how the things works, but Delphi is certainly a true RAD as they advertise.

Comment: Myabe the confusion was caused just by the words used in question phrasing. What you showed was how to **assign** a handler to an event. An event is no more than a property with a very specific datatype: a procedural type. As any other property, you can assing a value to an event. This value must be a procedural type too, which means here, the pointer to class method. That´s why you correctly used the operator `:=`. Delphi does not have native support to multicast events like C#, so a certain event can fire one and only one handler. That´s why you **assign** a handler and not **add** one.